# Accessing device motion in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

Because the `cordova-plugin-device-motion` plugin [is now deprecated](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion), I'm trying to use the W3C Accelerometer API in my Ionic 3 app:

```
// At the top of my TS file:
   declare var Accelerometer;

// In my component:
  let sensor = new Accelerometer();
  sensor.start();

  sensor.onreading = () => {
      console.log("Acceleration along X-axis: " + sensor.x);
      console.log("Acceleration along Y-axis: " + sensor.y);
      console.log("Acceleration along Z-axis: " + sensor.z);
  }

  sensor.onerror = event => console.log(event.error.name, event.error.message);
```

This works great testing in Chrome.

However, when I try running this on a real device (iPhone 6) using iOS platform `4.5.5`, I get an error: `Runtime Error: Can't find variable: Accelerometer`.

What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone have any insight into getting W3C device motion data in an Ionic 3 app? If `cordova-plugin-device-motion` is deprecated, what **should** I be using in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=Accelerometer) it's only a Chrome feature for now.
You might want to checkout the devicemotion event [DeviceMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation#Processing_motion_events)